# odb save using python

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm trying to add a new fieldoutput for an existing odb file using python. 
I opened the odb using this instruction:

```
odb = openOdb(path='my_odb_path',readOnly=False)
.
.
.
save.odb()
```

But, I get this error: "Database save failed.***ERROR: Attempt to truncate read only table."

Does anyone knows how to sole this problem?
Thank you,

Comment: i don't think its possible, but it also seems like you are trying to guess at things. Have you looked at the scripting manual?

Comment: Resolved! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are just using the wrong command to save it. Don't forget to close it also.

```
odb = openOdb(path='my_odb_path',readOnly=False)
.
.#add new field output...#
.
odb.save()
odb.close()
```